# An alternative (?) approach to differential ringoids

Tags: ct.category-theory, categorification

Recall that a derivation on a ring $R$ is a function $\partial:R\to R$ satisfying the Leibniz rule $$\partial(ab)=\partial(a)b+a\partial(b),$$ and a differential ring is just a ring equipped with a derivation -- viewing a ring as a one-object preadditive category, a ringoid is just a preadditive category. We can thusly define differential ringoids to be ringoids $\mathcal{R}$ equipped with a 'derivoid' category mapping $$\hat\partial:\mathcal{R}\to\mathcal{R}$$ satisfying the obvious Leibnizoid rule $$\hat\partial(f\circ g)=\hat\partial(f)\circ g+f\circ\hat\partial(g).$$ Note that since $\partial$ is not in general a ring homomorphism, we shouldn't generally expect $\hat\partial$ to be a functor.

> Is this related to/a special case of the notion of a [differential algebroid](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/differential+algebroid) mentioned on the nlab? If not, where can I read more about this notion or an appropriate generalization of it?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/2103.00938 there's plenty of reasons to expect that $\partial$ *is* a functor! (despite the fact that we do not consider the Leibniz rule with respect to composition, "composition" in a different sense is implicitly considered for the "chain rule" in remark 5)

Comment: @fosco Very cool, thank you!

Comment: Todd and I are working on the unabridged version of the paper right in this very moment. I should have closed this story two years ago but we keep finding new questions! :D 2-rigs are very rich of structure!

Comment: Understainding rings as algebras over associative operad, (multiplicative) homomorphisms are their morpisms as algebras; derivations are their morphisms as *infinitesimal algebras*. In other words, given an endomorphism in underlying monoidal category $d: E \to E$, we have different choices for defining $d^{\otimes 2}$: by diagonal, or by totalisation (or maybe something else! it depends on your monoidal structure).

Comment: Another thing: think about dg algebras. They are ordinary algebras with multiplication being a morphism of complexes. ...So, main question back to OP: what properties you want from your generalisation of derivation? Two general directions are 1) ordinary monoids in a category of objects-with-endomorphism, or  2) monoids with infinitesimal composition in some ordinary category. Each choice provides you with appropriate framework to go from single-object algebras to multi-object ones.

Comment: @DenisT Also cool, thank you -- do you know of a reference where I could read more about this view?

Comment: @AlecRhea I do not know any written text on this matters, it's just my 2 year old musings. I tried to understand "the unreasonable effectiveness of square zero derivations in the natural sciences", without any spectacular progress so far. Part about infinitesimal composition and infinitesimal algebras/modules is in any operad textbook, Loday-Valette, for example.